# Getting an array index from 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wasn't sure how to properly word the title.

I have 2 indexes from a 2D array (x and y) and need to multiply them together to get the index for a second array (1D), however it's not that simple 'cause if x or y equals zero, it'll return zero regardless of the other value.

I could get around this using nested loops shown below:

```
    int count = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < y; j++ )
    {
        count++;
    }
}

//count now equals desired value
```

...but that seems awfully impractical.

To me this seems like something that should be incredibly simple and I've put off asking until now, thinking that might be the case.

Comment: Why not `count = x * y`? It sounds like you might want something like `A[x][y] = B[y * A.length + x]`

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. I knew it was something simple, my heads not with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use the following data to create an example:

```
var array_2d = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]];
var array_1d = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

If all of your sub arrays have the same size, you can simply multiply your `i` index by `your sub array’s length`, in order to find the corresponding “row” of your 1 dimensional array. Then you can simply add the “column” index of your array.

But this would only work if you are working with width-fixed matrixes.

```
var sub_dimensional_array_length = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < array_2d.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array_2d[i].length; j++) {
        var array_1d_index = (sub_dimensional_array_length * i) + j;
        console.log(array_2d[i][j], array_1d[array_1d_index]);
    }
}
```